# Using CSS to align control inside a div

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, html, webforms

I want to center-align a GridView control in a `<div>`. But the GV seems to stay on top-left position of the div even after applying the methods below:

`text-align : center` and `vertical-align : middle` yields no results.

Neither does `position : relative` or `margin : auto`.

`<div align="center">` works for horizontal alignment, but can't find any form of `valign` for a `<div>`.

Layout so far:

```
<div id="content1" class="contentSingleCenter" >
    <asp:GridView ID="grdGrid" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.contentSingleCenter
{
    width : 80%;
    height : 200px;
    position: relative; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

My main requirement is that I **can't** use a table to do this.

Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: Is the gridview a fixed size? Sorry for my ninja edit.  I re-read the question. ;)

Comment: div height is fixed at 200px, GridView no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I've found a fix... `<align="center">` and a bit of padding seems to work : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RowStyle-VerticalAlign="Center" and RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not the GridView contents I want to align - I want to align the GV itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height: $height_of_box` combined with `text-align: center`, see http://jsfiddle.net/ugRd3/.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will only work if the content within is a one-liner. Ping me if you need to cater for multi-line content within your box.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and yes, while this does work, it seems to have different effects on different controls. For example, I tried this with a ASP GridView, ASP Button and DevExpress ASPxGridView. Button aligns properly, DevEx GridView stays on top-left of div, but the ASP GridView goes weird and strecthes each cell to 200px high.

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML your GV produces in order to style it properly? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but what did you mean? The markup for my ASP GridView (after strectching) is exactly the same as the one in the Q... but here it is: 

`<div id="content3" class="contentSingleCenter">
    <asp:GridView ID="c" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>
 </div>`

Comment: Nonono, I meant the HTML ASP produces when from your <asp:GridView ID="c" runat="server" ></asp:GridView>. Say you open your site in a browser and copy the source code produced please.

Comment: After putting some numbers in:

`<div id="content3" class="contentSingleCenter">
                <div>
 <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_c" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Item</th>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>0</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>2</td>
  </tr><tr>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr><tr>
 </table>
</div>
`

Comment: I now see what you're trying to do and have been playing with jsFiddle for some time now to try to center the table vertically and horizontally, but to no avail without the width being fixed/specified, rather than 80%... Also setting the height of the table would help greatly... Seems like if you don't have a fixed number of records in your Grid/table, it is not going to be possible to center it vertically and horizontally unless you wrap it in another table - which is a horrible solution. http://jsfiddle.net/ugRd3/1/ Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

using the attribute `line-height` might work for you, set it to the same as the height of the div

```
div.contentSingleCenter
{
    width : 80%;
    height : 200px;
    line-height: 200px; 
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, but I seems to have some problems with this... please see my comment to hoopyfrood's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.contentSingleCenter
{
    width : 80%;
    height : 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

Tested in modern browsers and working pretty well.  You can use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on the gridview for horizontal centering.

Comment: Without knowing anything else about your gridview, or other CSS on the page, it's difficult to solve the problem.  My answer works without any other factors involved, so perhaps there are other things going on preventing this from working.  Also, I'm using a strict doctype.  Should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

According to IE9, gridviews and formviews are translated into tables with rows, cols, etc...
Therefore, in order to get them centered use :

```
table
{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but here is what I found worked for me:

The asp:GridView control renders as a table nested inside a div.  Because of this, applying the style directly to the control does not produce the desired result.  I found that applying the style to the table child of the div container worked best in my application.  This is really just a permutation of JGM's answer above.

CSS:

```
.contentSingleCenter table
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I believe this method would be preferred to the accepted answer because it uses CSS instead of the deprecated align attribute.